# How do you create nested methods in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, class, methods, nested

For example, I've seen third-party applications that have functions like this:

```
$db->select('columns')->from('table')->where('condition');
```

That's just an example. How do you create methods like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To accomplish this, each of the methods should return `$this`, an instance of the class which contains the methods.

```
class MyClass {

   public function select($x){
      // do something
      return $this;
   }

   public function from($x){
      // do something
      return $this;
   }

   public function where($x){
      // do something
      return $this;
   }

}
```

inside these methods, you generally perform some kind of modification to the state of the object.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the methods are simply returning objects.  So `$db->select()` returns an object with a method `from()`, which returns an object with a method `where()`.